# Thread-safety based on object value

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

I need to create thread-safety on a Web-API method, but only when two requests containing the same property value are ran simultaneously.

I have created a mix of WaitHandles and a ConcurrentDictionary to only hold the threads that have another thread processing a similar item.

Is this code thread-safe? The one that worries me is the `ContainsKey` with the `TryAdd`.

```
private readonly static ConcurrentDictionary _processingGateways = new ConcurrentDictionary();

public Models.Profile GetProfile([FromBody] GetProfileRequest request)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new HttpError(ModelState, true)));

    if (_processingGateways.ContainsKey(request.GatewayId))
        _processingGateways[request.GatewayId].WaitOne();
    _processingGateways.TryAdd(request.GatewayId, new AutoResetEvent(false));

    // Wait for this until prev with same gatewayId has finished
    var device = _clientRegistrar.RegisterMobileEndpoint(Mapper.Map(request));

    AutoResetEvent currentHandle;
    _processingGateways.TryRemove(request.GatewayId, out currentHandle);
    currentHandle.Set();

    return Mapper.Map(device);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx), **all** public and protected members of `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` are **thread-safe** and may be used concurrently from **multiple threads**. However, concurrency only applies to the **individual actions** performed on the instance of the `ConcurrentDictionary`. The situation will not get messy, if a thread is performing a **write** operation and an another thread is performing a **read** operation at the same time. **But**, there is no protection within the  `ConcurrentDictionary` class against the situation, when an information of the **past** is provided, that has since **changed** and because of that, an invalid operation is performed.

I **do not** see the reason of calling `ContainsKey`, since an **another thread** could remove that particular element between the `ContainsKey` and the `Dictionary` value accessor operations and `KeyNotFoundException` will be thrown.

```
if (_processingGateways.ContainsKey(request.GatewayId))
// the element could be removed right at this point during execution
    _processingGateways[request.GatewayId].WaitOne(); // KeyNotFoundException is thrown here
_processingGateways.TryAdd(request.GatewayId, new AutoResetEvent(false));
```

The **key** to your solution could be the [`TryGetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267270(v=vs.110).aspx) method. It is going to lock the `ConcurrentDictionary` for reading and return the element (if it exists).

```
if (_processingGateways.TryGetValue(request.GatewayId, out var Gateway))
    Gateway.WaitOne();
_processingGateways.TryAdd(request.GatewayId, new AutoResetEvent(false));
```

*(Disclaimer: code uses C#7.0 out variables)*

Now your are secured against the exception.

If you inspect the code for possible deadlock situations, you might observe that it is possible, that `Set` gets executed before `WaitOne`. It is good to know, that the wait returns when all events are set and it does not matter, whether or not that happened before or after wait was called. **Great**, no deadlocks here!